# TimeStream + Grafana: Query to verify if the value of column is populated each minute

Tags: grafana, amazon-timestream

I need someone's help in determining a timeseries query on the basis of Timestream DB datasource in Grafana and set up the alert if the timestamp doesn't occur for a device in a duration of 10mins.

My initial data looks like below:

```
SELECT * FROM $__database.$__table where measure_name='Main' AND measure_value::bigint=51
```

[image]

Now here how can I create a Grafana alert using Timestream datasource if the data in `Main=51` in `not` published any second then through an alert.

I know I am asking a lot but just learning Timestream database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select count of events that happen within desired time-window and alert based on value of this count being lower then expected threshold.

Comment: how can I create a timeseries for it then ? because count won't help here.

Comment: because the per minute message is not fixed